# Consume Kafka messages with FastAPI and aiokafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, async-await, fastapi

I would like to create an API to consume message from Kafka topic with FastAPI.

I am trying to create an entrypoint with the code below:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import json
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException

from app.config import (
    TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST,
    KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

requests_router = r = APIRouter()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@r.get("/requests/{group_id}")
async def get_messages_from_kafka(group_id: str):
    # define consumer
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST,
        loop=loop,
        bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
        group_id=group_id,  # Consumer must be in a group to commit
        enable_auto_commit=True,  # Is True by default anyway
        auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,  # Autocommit every second
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",  # If committed offset not found, start from beginning
    )

    # start consumer
    await consumer.start()

    retrieved_requests = []
    try:
        data = await consumer.getmany()
        for tp, messages in data.items():
            for message in messages:
                # Process message
                retrieved_requests.append({
                        "key": messages.key.decode("utf-8"),
                        "value": json.loads(message.value.decode("utf-8")),
                    })
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error when trying to consume request for {group_id}: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()
    return retrieved_requests
```

I always end with an empty list. I don't understand why I cannot get messages from the topic configured.

I also try the "classic" async for loop in the [aiokafka doc](https://aiokafka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#aiokafkaconsumer). But it doesn't work neither. However, with the classic loop, I can see a consumer is created and some messages are comsumed. With the `getmany` it's always empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution with `getmany` from `aiokafka` consumer.

The idea is to try to get messages with consumer and setting a timeout if there is no (more) message(s). I set also a maximum number of message to retrieve in case there are too much message but it should be optional.

Here is the code:

```py
requests_router = r = APIRouter()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def kafka_json_deserializer(serialized):
    return json.loads(serialized)


@r.get("/requests/{group_id}")
async def get_messages_from_kafka(group_id: str):
    """
    Consume a list of 'Requests' from 'TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST'.
    """
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST,
        loop=loop,
        bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
        group_id=group_id,  # unique identifier for each sidecar
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,  # commit every second
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",  # If committed offset not found, start from beginning
        value_deserializer=kafka_json_deserializer,
    )

    logger.info(
        f"Start consumer with group ID: '{group_id}' on topic '{TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST}'."
    )
    await consumer.start()
    logger.info("Consumer started.")

    retrieved_requests = []
    try:
        result = await consumer.getmany(
            timeout_ms=CONSUMER_TIMEOUT_MS, max_records=MAX_RECORDS_PER_CONSUMER
        )
        logger.info(f"Get {len(result)} messages in {TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST}.")
        for tp, messages in result.items():
            if messages:
                for message in messages:
                    retrieved_requests.append(
                        {"key": message.key.decode("utf-8"), "value": message.value,}
                    )
                # await consumer.commit({tp: messages[-1].offset + 1})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f"Error when trying to consume request for {group_id} on topic {TOPIC_INGESTED_REQUEST}: {str(e)}"
        )
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()

    return retrieved_requests
```